# RESTful delete strategy

Tags: rest

Let's say I have a resource that can have two different behaviors when delete is called

1. The resource is deleted.
2. The resource is moved to the recycle bin.

How would model it in a REST compliant way?

I thought about the following solution:

```
DELETE /myresource
```

moves the resource to the recycle bin (default behavior)

```
DELETE /myresource?force-delete=true
```

forces delete on the resource.

Is that REST compliant? I have never seen query parameters in the URL when calling DELETE, is that OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure REST strategy should prefer non changing resources. In my opinion, you are not changing the resource by appending a parameter, so it sounds like good strategy to me.

If you were to perform the same action like so:

```
DELETE /myresource.force
```

that would act like another resource, which wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: This breaks the 'rules' of REST in that you are addressing a different resource. At the same time, so does /myresource.json and /myresource.xml providing different formats of the same data (use your accept headers, people!) but that isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: This is not 'REST', you are doing actions in an RPC fashion.

Answer (score 11):

Your idea is fine, but I think a custom request header would be a little more appropriate. Query parameters are better suited to, well, parameters.

A custom request header would look something like this:

```
DELETE /myresource
X-Really-Delete: Yup
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not? You are already passing a parameter to identify which resource, so send another one to establish a different course of action. IMO, it is perfectly RESTful.

Answer (score 2):

You could also implement 2. as a POST request instead of DELETE.

```
POST /myresource

recycle-bin=true...
```

As in all you're doing is updating the resource to indicate that it is in the recycle-bin.

**EDIT**: changed method from `PUT` to `POST` given a `PUT` must enclose a complete replacement (or addition) of the resource, whereas clearly here we are only updating a part of the resource.

Comment: I would argue against your change from PUT to POST. POST is for creating content, PUT is for modifications; all the OP is really doing is marking a resource with a certain value, ie updating it.

Comment: @thecoshman PUT is create or replace which requires the entire entity be enclosed in the request. Modifications could be made via the PATCH method but that has limited support.

Comment: erh... somewhat. PUT can be used to create content, as can POST. The difference being with PUT you create at a specific URI, whilst POST you are asking the server to work out what URI to store it as. PUT can also be used to complete replace a resource. You are right in saying that really PATCH is the correct method to make a minor update like this. In the absence of proper support, the 'proper' solution would be to GET the full resource, update it, and PUT the complete update resource back on the server, to the same URI.

Answer (score 2):

DELETE should delete the item, no questions asked.

Sadly, there is no 'MOVE' request in HTTP. POST is usually intended for creating content, PUT is more modifications.

So I would suggest you you do something like `PUT /myresource` with some form of meta-data or a  json string along the lines of `{ "recycle":"true" }` to indicate that you want to 'recycle' it.