# Delete operation in Restful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I've come across a situation in my webservice where in I've to delete a resource and update the other resources which are referring to this resource with other resource specified by user. How can I achieve this in RESTful way?

For example:
DELETE resource Agent/123
Some customers might be assigned to this agent, hence while deleting the Agent 123 user will specify another agent 125 for all these customers.

I thought of following ways:

DELETE request on the url Agent/123/125
On the server I'll handle this request at url Agent/123 and new agent id will be taken as 125.
I felt this is completely away from RESTful way, so thought of dropping this idea. Please let me know whether this restful way.

Another option is:
Delete Agent/123?ReAssignId=125

I'm not sure whether this is also restful way or not, I've come across this method in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512279/restful-delete-strategy). I'm still not convinced with this strategy as well.

Have any one come across this situation, how this situation should be handled in Restful way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I like the option `Delete Agent/123?ReAssignId=125` because the reassignment number is just a metavalue associated with the delete operation.  The core operation is a delete (resource gets removed and is no longer available).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an UPDATE operation and a DELETE later on when the new agent has been asigned for the customer(s). If both methods have to be somewhat atomic, I think the best REST-ful way would be to organize this on client.

Comment: You mean two requests should be sent to server for this operation. I was trying to avoid two requests to the server.

Comment: Also two requests means that the data will temporarily be in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

To be truly RESTful, you'll have to individually update each Customer resource, then delete the Agent.  But if you've realized that this is all more of a guideline than anything else, I really don't see any reason why you wouldn't use your ReAssignId technique.

Comment: What REST constraint is he violating?