# WebClient restful Delete

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

I have a simple Restful service being called from a console app so am using `WebClient`.  I am wondering if this call for Delete is correct.

The url looks like `localhost/RestService1/Person/1`

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) 
{
    client.UploadString(url, "DELETE", "");
}
```

I don't like that `UploadString` does not have an overload without a `data` parameter.  The passing of an empty parameter is not sitting well with me.  Is there a better method to use for a `DELETE`?

I could use `WebRequest` but I want to just use `WebClient` to keep it consistent.

Here is the `WebRequest` block

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "DELETE";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Both blocks work fine but what is best?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539394/rest-http-delete-and-parameters

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512279/restful-delete-strategy

Comment: Other than the relation to DELETE and RESTful in those references, I don't think `WebClient` really gives you the semantics of DELETE.  `Webclient` just uses `WebRequest` (`HttpWebRequest`) under the covers, so I think using `HttpWebRequest`) directly is more readable.

Comment: I don't think the first 2 links refer to my question.  My url is localhost/RestService1/Person/1  where /1 is the person Id, so it is restful.  I did a little more digging and see that WebClient is mostly a wrapper.  thanks

Answer (score 29):

The following works for me:

```
client.UploadValues(url, "DELETE", new NameValueCollection());
```

Comment: And if you need to provide additional parameters (e.g. api_key), you can provide them via query string in the url.

Comment: client.UploadString(url, "DELETE", string.Empty) worked as well

Answer (score 3):

The WebClient class doesn't really lend well to restful api consumption, I've used 3rd party libraries like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) in the past that are geared more towards this type of web request.  I'm pretty sure RestSharp just uses HttpWebRequest under the covers, but it provides a lot of semantics that make consuming and reusing rest resources easier.

Comment: I am using WebClient with Newtonsoft Json and it is very simple to use.  I'll look into RestSharp.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Go get the Microsoft.Net.Http client libraries http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

HttpClient is a much better client to use for working with an API.

Comment: This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Windows Store apps when consuming a library that uses this package.

Comment: @juFo It is supported in VS2010 and in .net 4.0.  I'm not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: I just quoted the link you provided: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Comment: @juFo  Aaah.  Unfortunately the content of that link changed since I posted it!  That's the pre-release "portable library" version of HttpClient.  If you go for the stable one you will get a .net 4/VS2010 compatible version.

Comment: HttpClient is clumsy in usage, since contains only ASYNC methods (what is not always desirable). Moreover - MS docs says HttpClient is NOT replacement for WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is my solution in vb.net i sure that anyone can translate to c#

It's very important  to drop headers, i had to comment header about Accept and Content-Type and work fine..... of course I did send the token

```
Dim rest As WebClient = New WebClient()
rest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " & Token)
'rest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json")
'rest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json")

result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rest.UploadValues(host_api & uri, "DELETE", New NameValueCollection()))
```